# Windows Store App can't find Bluetooth Arduino

Tags: windows, bluetooth, arduino, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to communicate with an Arduino over bluetooth using the Windows.Networking.Sockets namespace for Windows 8.1 Store apps. For some reason PeerFinder can't find the Arduino and the pairedDevices collection is empty.  I manually paired the Arduino in the Settings App in Windows, so I know the problem isn't the Arduino code.  If anyone can help me fix my code so I can find the Arduino it'd be much appreciated

```
PeerFinder.Start();
PeerFinder.AllowBluetooth = true;
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = string.Empty;
var pairedDevices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

int i = 0;
//Look for paired Arduino
while (i <= pairedDevices.Count)
{
    if (pairedDevices[i].DisplayName == "HC-05")
    {
    break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you find any devices?

Comment: No. The pairedDevices.count = 0.